# How can I get 'payload' property from the Messages list? Gmail API

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I'm new in node, and I want to get info about my gmail messages, like who's wrote the message and the text. 
I follow quickstart exemple and write the following code, but there are just 'id' and 'threadId' field in output.

```
function listMessages(auth) {
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    gmail.users.messages.list({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me'
    }, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        var messages = response.messages;
        if (messages.length == 0) {
            console.log('No messages found.');
        } else {
            console.log('Messages:');
            for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                var message = messages[i];
                console.log(message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Could somebody explain me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`messages.list()` API returns only the message IDs and thread IDs by design. If you need to get details of those messages you need to make another API call `messages.get()` to get specific details of each message.

> API reference:
>   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

While this will work, you may want to have a look at GMail's batch operations which allow getting details of messages in one call (with limitations though).

> Google's guide on batch:
>   https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

Similar queries have been answered here at SO:

- [Gmail API all messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658969/gmail-api-all-messages)
- [Gmail API Users.messages: list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484791/gmail-api-users-messages-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

add "`me`" as `userId` and add your message id in `messageId` filed. others fields are optional.