# GMail API - messages().list() only returns message IDs

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-python-client

The list() method only returns a list of message IDs without any other message metadata. 
There are SO posts [from 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25494460/399302) and [2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40960785/399302), but the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#response) states that the response is a list of [user.messages resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) ...

Is the documentation wrong or is there any other way to do this? I understand that bringing the entire message in a "list" call is not efficient for a REST API call - but maybe returning "some" metadata would make sense (e.g. output of service.users().messages().get(..., format='metadata')) as opposed to making a call to list() and then, for every message, make a get(..., format='metadata')

Thanks!

M

Comment: You need to list the message ids, and then get each message separately. There is no way around that, sadly. You can bring down the total amount of requests from `1 + N of messages` to 2 if you get all the messages in a [**batch request**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24562981/bulk-fetching-emails-in-the-new-gmail-api).

Comment: @Tholle good answer

Comment: Thanks @Tholle I figured that, was just hoping the documentation was right ;)

Comment: Yes, apparently the documentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

```
gmail.users.messages.get({
auth: auth,
userId: 'me',
id: messageid,
format: "raw"
}, function (err, response) { 
});
```

You have to call the above api with each messageid. The response will be raw data for corresponding email