# Retrieve all emails from Gmail i did but only got 3000 email not all

Tags: python, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-python-client

What is the way to pull out all emails from Gmail?

I did `full_sync`, but that didn't return all of my email - only about 3000 emails, while I know I have more. In the documentation they did not mention about this.

My code snippet:

```
    history = service.users().history().list(
        userId='me',
        startHistoryId=start_history_id,
        maxResults=500,
        labelId='INBOX'
    ).execute()
    if "history" in history:
        try:
            for message in history["history"]:
                   batch.add(
                    service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message["messages"][0]["id"]),
                    callback="somecallbak",
                    request_id=request_id
                )
            batch.execute()
    while 'nextPageToken' in history:
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  The gmail api should be returning all emails assuming you are using pagination to get the next page of data

Comment: yes while the next token come it will hit

Comment: if you're using the Python Client, use their `list` and `list_next` methods as suggested in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/pagination

Answer (score 4):

If you are doing a full sync, you should refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync) documentation, that recommends two steps:

- listing all the messages with the [users.messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) method
- for each of the entry get the required information using the [users.messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method

So you don't need use the [users.history.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) as you will have an hard time finding the `startHistoryId` from which to start.

You can achieve this with a snipped similar to the one below (tested and working on my python 3.x console). As suggested by others I used the python client [pagination](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/pagination) and [batch](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch) request functionalities.

```
from httplib2 import Http
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client import client, tools, file


# callback for the batch request (see below)
def print_gmail_message(request_id, response, exception):
    if exception is not None:
        print('messages.get failed for message id {}: {}'.format(request_id, exception))
    else:
        print(response)


# Scopes
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', ]

# where do we store our credentials?
creds_store = file.Storage('gmail-list.json')
start_creds = creds_store.get()

# standard oauth2 authentication flow
if not start_creds or start_creds.invalid:
    # client_id.json is exported from your gcp project
    start_flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    start_creds = tools.run_flow(start_flow, creds_store)

# Gmail SDK
http = Http()
gmail_sdk = build('gmail', 'v1', http=start_creds.authorize(http))

# messages.list parameters
msg_list_params = {
    'userId': 'me'
}
# messages.list API
message_list_api = gmail_sdk.users().messages()
# first request
message_list_req = message_list_api.list(**msg_list_params)

while message_list_req is not None:
    gmail_msg_list = message_list_req.execute()

    # we build the batch request
    batch = gmail_sdk.new_batch_http_request(callback=print_gmail_message)
    for gmail_message in gmail_msg_list['messages']:
        msg_get_params = {
            'userId': 'me',
            'id': gmail_message['id'],
            'format': 'full',
        }
        batch.add(gmail_sdk.users().messages().get(**msg_get_params), request_id=gmail_message['id'])

    batch.execute(http=http)

    # pagination handling
    message_list_req = message_list_api.list_next(message_list_req, gmail_msg_list)
```

Comment: Thanks yes it worked fine for the standalone script, but I am using with diffrent library so i dont have the customer token file json ,module that  i am using  import google.oauth2.credentials
import googleapiclient.discovery                         kind of stuck with authentication flow

Comment: can you update the original post with a more complete snippet?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658969/gmail-api-all-messages), you may use [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch).

> Use batch and request 100 messages at a time. You will need to make 1000 requests but the good news is that's quite fine and it'll be easier for everyone (no downloading 1GB response in a single request!).

Also based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41761245/gmail-api-pagination-use-of-nextpagetoken), *you could save the next page token on every request and use it in your next request. If there is no next page token in the response, you know that you have gotten all messages.*

Comment: ". If there is no next page token in the response, you know that you have gotten all messages.

"  i have more than 9000 emails in my inbox  but still every time it pulls only 3000